# Activity to Fragment Bundle not being received

Tags: android, fragment, bundle

**UPDATE: This is my current code, however it breaks after I re-click the same button.... 
Cause: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already active**

I have a `main_activity.xml` split into Frame layouts. 
The upper frame layout contains an edit text and 3 buttons (small, medium, large). 
The lower frame layout contains a text view to populate the text of the edit text in either small, medium or large font.

I put the text into a bundle and am attempting to reopen that bundle in the corresponding fragment once the button is clicked.... however, the bundle does not contain any text information from the text according to my debugger.

Here is my code with the medium, large buttons removed

Any help, please?

**MainActivity:**

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 TextView textView;
 Button bSmall;
 Small fSmall = new Small();
  Bundle bundle = new Bundle();



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if(findViewById(R.id.fragment)!=null){
            if(savedInstanceState!=null){
                return;
            }

        }

        final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.type_here);

        final Button bSmall = (Button)findViewById(R.id.small);
        Button bMedium = (Button)findViewById(R.id.medium);

        bSmall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                String message_small = editText.getText().toString();
                small = message_small;

                bundle.putString("message_small", message_small);
                fSmall.setArguments(bundle);
                FragmentManager fm =getFragmentManager();

                FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.fragment, fSmall).commit();


            }

        });

        bMedium.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String message_medium = editText.getText().toString();
                bundle.putString("message_medium", message_medium);
                fMedium.setArguments(bundle);
                FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.fragment, fMedium).commit();
            }
        });



    }

    public String getMyData(){
        return small;
    }
}



Small:

public class Small extends Fragment {

    EditText editText;
    View myView;




    public Small() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_small, container, false);

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle = getArguments();
        MainActivity activity = (MainActivity)getActivity();
        //String dataFromMainActivity = activity.getMyData();


        String myString = bundle.getString("message_small");
        TextView set = myView.findViewById(R.id.small_text);
        set.setText(myString);

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        return myView;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add the bundle to the fragment. 
You need to do something like this:

```
 Small fSmall = new Small();
 ...
 bundle.putString("message_small", message_small);
 fSmall.setArguments(bundle);

 FragmentManager fm =getFragmentManager();

 FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
 ft.replace(R.id.fragment, fSmall);
```

Comment: Thanks, I added fSmall.setArguments(bundle), however the problem appears to be that String myString = getArguments().getString("message_small"); is empty.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to add your bundle to your Fragment before calling the fragment manager.

You should try something like this:

```
Small fSmall = new Small();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("message_small", message_small);   //parameters are (key, value).
fSmall.setArguments(bundle);

getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment, fSmall).commit();
```

In your second fragment, you should check if `myString` is not null or empty.

```
String myString = getArguments().getString("message_small");
if (myString == null) {
    Log.e("TAG", "Error: null argument");
}
```

**EDIT** I see another problem here. You are accessing varaibles that have not been instatiated. You should inflate your layout before calling `findViewById()` or it will return a `NullPointerException`.

Update your `Small` class like this :

```
public class Small extends Fragment {
 private EditText editText;
 View myView;

 public Small() {
  // Required empty public constructor
 }

 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  // Inflate the layout for this fragment
  myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_small, container, false);

  String myString = getArguments().getString("message_small");

  // Here, myView is != null 
  TextView editText = myView.findViewById(R.id.small_text);

  // Here, editText is != null
  editText.setText(myString);

  return myView;
 }
}
```

Best

Comment: If myString is not existing, what could the cause be?.

Comment: You should see if `getArguments()` return null or if `getString()` return null first. Then we'll see.

Comment: bundle = getArguments(); is null.

Comment: Can you edit your first post and add your new code with what I've wrote above ?  It's weird.

Comment: And I edited my post as I saw another problem to your code.